# Problem to install Firebase SDK (Analytics,Database,Messaging),Facebook SDK, Playfabs SDK on Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, playfab

I'm developing  a card game with Unity3d for Android and iOS device. I need to use Firebase SDK for chat system, Playfabs and Facebook SDK for login method. When I try to install all sdk in my project, I have a lot of problems because there are much error.

There isn't any script because I choose to create a new project and I only install sdk.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yXR4.png)

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.Editor.Measurement' threw an exception. ---> System.MissingMethodException: void Google.EditorMeasurement.set_InstallSourceFilename(string)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Firebase.Editor.AndroidSettingsChecker..cctor () [0x0000c] in Z:\tmp\tmp.pxoeYNk3oG\firebase\app\client\unity\editor\src\AndroidAPILevelChecker.cs:37 
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes(Type[])

MissingMethodException: void Google.EditorMeasurement.set_InstallSourceFilename(string)
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.Editor.Measurement' threw an exception.
Firebase.Editor.AndroidSettingsChecker..cctor () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.pxoeYNk3oG/firebase/app/client/unity/editor/src/AndroidAPILevelChecker.cs:37)
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Firebase.Editor.AndroidSettingsChecker' threw an exception.
System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) (at <fb001e01371b4adca20013e0ac763896>:0)
UnityEditor.AssetPostprocessingInternal.GetMeshProcessorsHashString () (at <a0a9ad37e16b4f7cb955e1101b72d4cc>:0)
UnityEditor.AssetPostprocessingInternal:GetMeshProcessorsHashString()
```

They are the error. Somebody have the same problems? Any solution?

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

When install all this SDK we must start from Firebase sdk. Don't install analitycs sdk, install only messagging. Import on the manifest the dependencies and from now we must decline all changes and merges. The last one sdk must be Facebook sdk